# soft linewrap width

Tags: gvim, wrapping

When wrapping text in GVim, the wrap occurs at the right side of the GVim window. I would prefer to have it wrap at column 80 however. A solution I have found is to `:set columns=80`, but this shrinks the window and gives me a kind of claustrophobic feeling. Therefore I was wondering whether anyone knows a way to wrap the text at a fixed column, without modifying the file on disk and without modifying the GVim window size. A fixed size blank space on the right of the screen would also work, but would not have my preference.

If it makes a difference: I'm mainly using GVim 7.4 on a Windows machine.

Comment: Found an older duplicate, here: [Force (visual-only) wrap at specific column regardless window size in gVim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/force-visual-only-wrap-at-specific-column-regardless-window-size-in-gvim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One non-Ideal solution is open another window and then set the vertical res to 80. The command would be:

```
:vnew | wincmd p | vertical res 80
```

I know this isn't *quite* what you had in mind, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: It's indeed non-ideal, but comes very close. I hadn't thought of using the extra space for something usefull, but maybe i can even put the extra window to good use. The fact that the columns resize when resizing the window is not very important to me, but can indeed be a nuisance.I'll wait a bit and see if anyone comes up with an even better idea, otherwise I'll accept this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. There are many many ways to configure how a wrap should occur, such as with `textwidth` and `wrapmargin`, but these are only for hardwraps, not softwraps. The only way to change a softwrap is by changing your window size.

There are some plugins that *sort of* do what you want, where the wrap occurs in an area smaller than your window. There is [mikewest/vimroom](https://github.com/mikewest/vimroom) and [junegunn/goyo.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim), but for both of these, a smaller softwrap is mainly just a side-effect of the main purpose of the plugin: To declutter your vim window and remove distractions.

An ugly workaround could be to open a split and resize it to column 80, but this hardly feels like an ideal solution. (Especially since the location of the split will change when you resize your window)