# Is there a soft/visual textwrap equivalent option?

Tags: formatting, wrapping, line-breaks

I like `textwidth`, except that it inserts EOL characters, and that breaks what I consider to be a sentence. I'd like to go back to having a long sentence be a long sentence, but I want it visually broken.

`wrapmargin` also inserts EOLs and seems to just go from the right side of the screen, not the left, so that's out.

`linebreak` *sounds* like what I want, but, it seems like it allows you to fill the screen *and then* defines what character to break at; this is not what I want. Rather, I want to break at some definitive point like I can with textwidth (e.g. character 80) but without the EOL.

Does the option I want exist?

Comment: Presumably you mean `'textwidth'`...

Comment: @BLayer Whoops, thanks.

Comment: See `:h 'wrap'`

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible, although there are various workarounds: [soft linewrap width](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/soft-linewrap-width), [goyo plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim), [Soft wrap at 80 characters in Vim in window of arbitrary width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/989093/328936)

Answer (score 0):

There is `wrap` option that does almost what you want.

"Almost", because it wraps around window boundaries, not some defined textwidth:

[image]