# How to soft wrap at column number greater than window width?

Tags: wrapping

Imagine a 30-character line shown in a 20-character wide window. How can I soft wrap it at the 25th column?

With `:set nowrap`

```
|01234567890123456789|0123456789
|       window       |
```

After scrolling till 25th character.

```
01234|56789012345678901234|56789
     |       window       |
```

Desired behaviour:

```
01234|56789012345678901234|
     |56789               |
     |       window       |
```

I tried `:set columns` with a large number but it messed up other elements like statusline.

A similar [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/force-visual-only-wrap-at-specific-column-regardless-window-size-in-gvim) instead concerns with setting column number smaller than the window width.

Comment: Why not turn on wrap, which does this? You can scroll left and right with zl and zh i think

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `:set wrap` won't have the specified behavior (3rd example).

Comment: There is no built-in way to do what you want, and I don't think that implementing that with a plugin would be possible (I could be wrong tho)

Comment: Vim doesn't really have any soft wrapping capabilities. See: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1847

Answer (score 1):

I thought I found a good example of what *can't* be done with Vim. (Un)fortunately I was wrong.

The specified behavior can be accomplished by:

1. Concealing first `n` characters of every line. E.g. `:syn match Concealed '^.\{25\}' conceal`

   1. `n` is determined by the current `1 + virtcol(".") - wincol()`.
   2. This needs to be updated on every [WinScrolled (Neovim only)](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5181) event.
2. Setting `concealcursor=nvic`.
3. `:set wrap`

Comment: This is an abomination. I love it!

Comment: The answer could be improved by a). including the code! b). adding a plain-English explanation of how it works.